# Is the rails update controller method expected to be for one object only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I often use ajax to update or delete objects in the controller. Now, there are the update and destroy methods, which generally look for a single id and perform actions on it. But I often need to to perform the same action to multiple objects. I can modify the update method to grab ids as an array and loop through them, to where whether it's one id or several, it will perform the same action to each - or create a nearly identical method for update_all. Is it wise to try to use update as an update_all method, or is it confusing? The downside of an update_all method seems like it would be very similar code, but done for all.

Is update in the controller expected to always be for one object? What are best practices and what do people normally do?

Comment: Are you referring to the ActiveRecord `update` method on a model, or the `update` method created in a controller when you generate a scaffold?  It sounds like you may mean the latter, but it's unclear.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, the method in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer not to drastically alter the conceptual behavior of the 7 "out of the box" actions. If someone else comes along and tries to work in that code they will likely be confused as to why you changed it from the normal/usual update action behavior. Instead I would add a collection route named descriptively (update_many or something like that).

Also, can you abstract out the common code to dry things out?

Comment: I am thinking along these lines as well - the main 7 actions seem like they should remain essentially untouched. Also thinking about duplicate code... I'm thinking it's probably just the initial query and then the updating itself, although the subsequent js that would happen alter (render partial) can probably be abstracted out.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `update` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (the result of a lookup) and it will update all of the objects.  Under the hood this is basically a convenience method that does the loop you described and calls update on each object.  (See: the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update))

There's also an `update_all` method that works similarly to `delete` in that it just sends the query to the database.  This will update all of the records with one query.  However, this **does not** execute any of the rails validations or callbacks.  In practice this severely limits the usefulness of this method for day to day coding.  I've found this method more useful for bulk activities in special scripts.

Some commentary:

One of the downsides to Rails and ActiveRecord specifically is that its callback model is based around single record interactions with the database.  While this makings coding incredibly wonderful, it makes large batch transactions really heavy.  I've personally spent a lot of time working through (or around) this drawback.  In the large, it's worth it for the other benefits.

Comment: I think you may have also been confused by my post. I was speaking more generally about the update method in the controller, not updating directly on the object. Unless I misunderstood your answer.